# Sum Checked Radio Button Value not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I currently try to sum radio button selected value, but I can't make it work, what am i missing?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function calcscore(){
        var score = 0;
        var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("r1");
        for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
            if(ele[i].checked) {
                score += parseInt(ele[i].value);
            }
        }
        $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
    }

    function change(){

        $("val.(score)").change(function(){
            calcscore()
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="r1" type="radio" name="a2" value="9" />Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="r1" type="radio" name="a2" value="18" />Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="r1" type="radio" name="a2" value="10" />Option 3
    </label>
    <br />
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="r1" type="radio" name="a3" value="10" />Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="r1" type="radio" name="a3" value="10" />Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="r1" type="radio" name="a3" value="10" />Option 3
    </label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="sum" />
</form>
```

if you can find what is wrong, can you give me detail per line so I can learn from it?

Thankyou

Comment: Any console errors? The `change()` global function doesn't seem to be called or added as an event handler. Not a jQuery expert but `val.(score)` doesn't look like a valid selector.

Comment: this the console error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$("val.(score)").` is not valid element you are calling on change function.

I have assigned a class `.score` OR you can also use `.r1` to all the input types you have which will be called on `change` function

Also consider using total `jQuery` or Pure `JS` not ideal to mix both to avoid confusions.

I have added both `jQuery` only solution as well below you can choose what suits you best.

Mix of JS and jQuery as per **your code**

Run Snippet below to see it working.

```js
function calcscore() {
  var score = 0;
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("r1");
  for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    if (ele[i].checked) {
      score += parseInt(ele[i].value);
    }
  }
  $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
}

function change() {

  $(".score").on('change', function() {
    calcscore()
  });
}

change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1 score" type="radio" name="a2" value="9">Option 1
    </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1 score" type="radio" name="a2" value="18">Option 2
    </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1 score" type="radio" name="a2" value="10">Option 3
    </label>
  <br>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1 score" type="radio" name="a3" value="10">Option 1
    </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1 score" type="radio" name="a3" value="10">Option 2
    </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1 score" type="radio" name="a3" onchange=() value="10">Option 3
    </label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="sum" />
</form>
```

**Using Jquery Only and with [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function**

if you want to do this via jQuery only. Here is working code.

We can use `.r1` class and use `:checked` to check which element is check and get it value via data of `.each` and sum it up that way.

```js
function calcscore(_this) {
  var score = 0;
  $('.r1:checked').each(function(index, data) {
    score += parseInt(data.value);
  })
  $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
}

function change() {
  $(".score").on('change', function() {
    calcscore()
  });
}

change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1 score" type="radio" name="a2" value="9">Option 1
    </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1 score" type="radio" name="a2" value="18">Option 2
    </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1 score" type="radio" name="a2" value="10">Option 3
    </label>
  <br>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1 score" type="radio" name="a3" value="10">Option 1
    </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1 score" type="radio" name="a3" value="10">Option 2
    </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1 score" type="radio" name="a3" value="10">Option 3
    </label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="sum" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why not use the `.r1` class name?

Comment: I just wanted to be more specific. Yes that's can be used as well.

Comment: You may want to mention that mixing jQuery with builtin JavaScript DOM methods is unnecessary.

Comment: `jQuery.each` would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: @hev1 Feel free to post your answer.

Comment: may i ask something ? `each(function(index, data)` what is index use for ?

Comment: @DoxTheaugbey Its getting the index of each element which is checked with class `.r1` so if two elements are checked the first index with 0 and second will 1. I am not sure what wrong with my i provided you more detailed answer and also provided either Javascript or ony jQuery method.

Comment: ah i see, thanks to you @AlwaysHelping, i accepted the answer. so there is more ways to achieve my case, thankyou.

Comment: @DoxTheaugbey You are welcome - Thanks alot. i appreciate it.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping i get some error when i use the script with laravel here is some error when i check using jshint.
```function calcscore(_this) {
  var score = 0;
  $('.r1:checked').each(function(index, data) {
    score += parseInt(data.value);
  })
  $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
}

function change() {
  $(".score").on('change', function() {
    calcscore()
  });
}

change()
```
Four warnings
16 Missing semicolon.
17 Missing semicolon.
22 Missing semicolon.
26 Missing semicolon.
One undefined variable
14 $
17 $
21 $

can i get help with this ?

Comment: @DoxTheaugbey You have to put up another question for the errors you getting in laravel. This question does not relate to laravel at all. I would recemend add another  question so someone can help. There could be multiple things in laravel specifically.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping also i get warn from console like this : Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Comment: @AlwaysHelping but logically it should work fine right ? or laravel have different environment for that ?

Comment: @DoxTheaugbey Yes different environment - different way of loading. So many thing to look for. Just simple jQuery and HTML my answer will working fine.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes indeed, you are right. so in laravel has blade stack, i add ```@push``` in my child view and put the js library in parent blade, and then call it. the script work now, thanks.

Comment: @DoxTheaugbey I am glad to hear that. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `$("val.(score)")` is not valid element. Use `$(".r1")` instead.

Secondly, `change()` function should trigger to register input change. You can do that by call `change()` at the end, or using jQuery event listener (as function inside)

```js
function calcscore() {
  var score = 0;
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("r1");
  for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    if (ele[i].checked) {
      score += parseInt(ele[i].value);
    }
  }
  $("input[name=sum]").val(score);
}

$(".r1").change(calcscore);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1" type="radio" name="a2" value="9">Option 1
    </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1" type="radio" name="a2" value="18">Option 2
    </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1" type="radio" name="a2" value="10">Option 3
    </label>
  <br>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1" type="radio" name="a3" value="10">Option 1
    </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1" type="radio" name="a3" value="10">Option 2
    </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
      <input class="r1" type="radio" name="a3" value="10">Option 3
    </label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="sum" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, it's work like charm. but for what script source use for ? am i need other libs for this ? and if i add more radio button inline the js script still same ?

Comment: I suppose that you already have `jQuery` in your real code. Script inject here to make sure you can run from snippet.